# Pattern Matcher valid number java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to have a number validation. Rules are:

1. A number can start with + or - or nothing (it is taken as a positive number)
2. Cannot start with 0
3. Can have a fraction either . or ,
4. Cannot end with 0

So acceptable numbers are: +123, -123, 123, 1023, 123.03, 123,03.
Non acceptable numbers are: 001, 1.000, any letters

I give you the expression that I ve built so far, on Dan's Tools. I have managed almost everything, except expressions after the the fraction. Every help is acceptable.

Expression: `(^(\+|-?)([1-9]+))([0-9]+)(\.|,?)`

Thanks in advance
Nikos

Comment: `(\+|-?)` means "a plus OR optionally a minus. Although that does give the result you want, it's a bit obscure. Writing `(\+|-)?` would better represent what you're doing. Since the two choices are both single characters, using a character class would be even better: **`[+-]?`** --- Note that `+` is not special in a character class, so it doesn't need escaping. Although `-` is special, it doesn't need escaping if placed first or last.

Comment: You can simply change last group `(\.|,?)` with `((\.|,)([1-9]+))?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except the fractional part that is missing in your pattern, your regex won't match single digit numbers as you quantified `[1-9]` and `[0-9]` with `+` quantifier requiring at least one char.

You can use

```
^[+-]?[1-9][0-9]*(?:[.,][0-9]*[1-9])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sm3dYI/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5B%2B-%5D%3F%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D*(%3F%3A%5B.%2C%5D%5B0-9%5D*%5B1-9%5D)%3F%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[+-]?` - an optional `+` or `-`
- `[1-9]` - a single non-zero digit
- `[0-9]*` - zero or more digits
- `(?:[.,][0-9]*[1-9])?` - an optional fractional part: `.` or `,` and then zero or more digits followed with a single non-zero digit
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: great explanation. Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: there has been a twist on the plot. On the above answer the 0.0 was not accepted as match, while i want it to be accepted. I tried to manage that with this: (^[+-]?)(0?|[1-9][0-9]*)([,.]?)(0{1}|[0-9][1-9]*)$
But now there is a match even for 0123 or 00123, which is not acceptable. A hint is that 000123 (3 zeros make it not acceptable.) I cant figure out what do i do wrong.

Comment: @NIKOLAOSKOSMATOS Now, it is rather unclear. Try `^[+-]?(?:0|[1-9][0-9]*)(?:[.,](?:[0-9]*[1-9]|0))?$`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sm3dYI/2).